# sed multiple repacement in a line

Tags: regex, sed

It may be a very basic question but I am not able to form the sed on liner for this.

Consider this line

```
foo@some_text/48183 bar@another-test/22787 xyz@some_another_text/2291
```

I want to replace everything from "@" to space separated by comma.
So my expected output should look like

```
foo,bar,xyz
```

I was trying  `sed -e 's/@.*[^ ]/,/g'` to replace till space however it is replacing whole whole line(not so good in writing regular exp).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Which expression does not work for you?

Comment: Please add your efforts which you have tried to solve this problem in your post too in CODE TAGS as we all are here to learn.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/([^@]+)@[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*/\1,/g' | sed 's/,$//'`

Comment: Thanks, it is working, can you please post is as answer and also little explanation will be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find and capture any 1+ chars other than `@` before a `@` char, then match `@` and any 0+ chars other than whitespace followed with 0+ whitespace chars, and replace all that with a placeholder to Group 1 and a comma. Then, you will have to remove the trailing comma.

See a [sed demo](http://rextester.com/TCP98461):

```
s='foo@some_text/48183 bar@another-test/22787 xyz@some_another_text/2291'
echo "$s" | sed -E 's/([^@]+)@[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*/\1,/g' | sed 's/,$//'
```

Note that you may also use `sed 's/\([^@][^@]*\)@[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*/\1,/g'` insead of the POSIX ERE version. In BRE POSIX, you should escape `(` and `)` to form a capturing group, and `+` quantifier should be escaped, or replaced with a `aa*` construction.

**Details**

- `([^@]+)` - Capturing group 1: 1+ chars other than `@`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[^[:space:]]*` - 0+ chars other than whitespace
- `[[:space:]]*` - 0+ whitespace chars

The `\1` is a placeholder for the text captured with the capturing group #1.

The second `sed 's/,$//'` is used to remove the trailing `,` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(/@.*/,"",$i)}} 1'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Taking code from Wiktor Stribizew's post and modifying it a bit to convert it to a single `sed` now.

```
sed -E 's/([^@]+)@[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*/\1,/g;s/,$//'  Input_file
```

Comment: Nice double `awk`, `sed` solution ;-) +1! Looks like I arrived a bit too late to answer this case lol

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem with the match part of your regex (`@.*[^ ]`) is that `.*`
matches almost the **whole rest** of the source string after the first `@`
(a quite common error) and `[^ ]` matches the last non-space char.

If you use `@\S+\s*` as the match part, then `\S+` matches "non-space" part
(e.g. `some_text/48183`) and `\s*` matches optional spaces thereafter.

This replacement gives `foo,bar,xyz,`, so you should somehow delete the last comma.

Comment: As you pointed out, there are two distinct operations needed to solve this problem, perhaps `sed 's/@\S*\s/,/g;s/@\S*//' file` might be suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it the other way around even if it might be a bit more `pipy`.

```
$ echo "foo@some_text/48183 bar@another-test/22787 xyz@some_another_text/2291" | (tr ' ' ',' | grep -oP '(?=,|^)[^@]+' | tr -d '\n'; echo "")
foo,bar,xyz
```

Instead of replacing, part of the string you can directly extract the relevant parts.

**Explanations:**

- `tr ' ' ','` in order to replace all spaces by commas.
- `grep -oP '(?=,|^)[^@]+'` to fetch everything before the `@`. It uses perl regex with lookaround (imposing the constraint that the preceding character is either a comma or the beginning of the string and accept all the characters except `@`.
- `tr -d '\n'` is used to remove the EOL inserted by `grep`
- the `echo ""` may be omitted if you do not need to have an ending `\n`. You can then simplify the command in `tr ' ' ',' | grep -oP '(?=,|^)[^@]+' | tr -d '\n'`